# getting the error : invalid syntax for tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Have install tensorflow in conda in different environment.

still getting error while importing tensorflow.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-1-64156d691fe5>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 111
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

please help me what to do i have also change path for python still issue persist.

Comment: `async` is a keyword in python3.5+. Are you sure you're installing the correct version of TF?

Comment: How to check that can you help me with this, please?

Comment: I am using python 3.7.10

Comment: Have you checked instructions from latest TF [document] (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) in 2.8/2.9 version.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this issue is to reinstall TensorFlow in the environment where you are seeing this error. You can do this by running the following command in your Conda environment:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow
```